# How Can I Use setValue() Based Off Of 2 Arrays That Match Value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I should start with letting you know that I'm an extreme novice in JS. My background is almost solely in SQL/VBA. So, any tips you could provide would be greatly appreciated, whether it's in coding or in Stack Overflow etiquette.

**Problem Background:**
I've got a Script that I use for sending outbound e-mails from Google Form responses, hosted within a Google Sheet and set to OnFormResponse(). Typically, I'm only asked to send back specific bits of information from the form responses within a HTML template e-mail. However, the business case I have now is that I need to look up the values from another sheet, where an adjacent column's value matches a form response value. With the value that's matched, I need to set the value of a specific column/row (F:F) within the Form Response sheet with it.

**Example:**
Here's a simplified version of what the Form Responses sheet looks like, along with the formula that I would typically use:
[image]

Here's what the other tab, 'Unique Databases!', looks like:

[image]

So, my understanding of JavaScript arrays is that on the Form Responses Sheet, I would load all columns (A:E in this example) into a variable, and get the values. Then, get columns A:B of 'Unique Databases!', which loads those values into another array. If that is accurate, how do you compare the index of 1 array against the index of another, and return an adjacent match?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this function:

```
function dbmanager(dbname) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Unique Databases!');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var r='';
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(dbname==vA[i][0]){
      r=vA[i][1];
      break;
    }
  }
  return r;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need to use a apps script to make a comparison like this. Perhaps a much faster way would be to use a query in the sheet. Something like this maybe:

```
 =QUERY(Sheet1!A1:B3,"SELECT B WHERE A ='"&E2&"'",0)
```

The first part of the query is looking up the unique databases data. The second part selects column B in the unique databases data where column A is equal to the data base name in the form responses data. Note this query goes in column F of the responses data.

Another alternative using code might be something [like this.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nqj-6U5wr9nDSASfHnPBRpEtXfQHwo-25mcQwEeYMts/edit?usp=sharing) with the code below running.

```
function getFormData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var getRange = sheet.getRange('E2:E');
  var data = getRange.getValues();
  var lookup = getLookupData();
  data.forEach(function(item,index){
    sheet.getRange(index + 2 , 6).setValue(lookup[item])
  })

}

function getLookupData() {
  var obj = {};
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:B6');
  var data = range.getValues();
  data.forEach(function(item){
    obj[item[0]] = item[1];    
  })
  Logger.log(obj)
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jason, so I'm trying to record the values as they existed at that point in time. Database managers can change over time, so using a formula would mean that any historic changes wouldn't be caught. That was my first thought too, and why I was using index(match()). However, if Person 1 Managed Database 1 at the time of the form submission, I'm trying to record that value. That way, if Person 2 switched to Database 1 tomorrow, it wouldn't affect that form submission.